C# list initialization using [] fails in both NET48 and NET6.0 projects
I inherited a C# project, it targets net48 and net6.0 as below:
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net48;net6.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>

it has the following code that is failing when compile:
private List<string> Names = [];

The error is: Invalid expression term '['
I tried to compile for net48 exclusively or net6.0 exclusively, it still fails with the same error message. I know I can just rewrite it in another way, but still puzzled by this.

Collection expressions are a new C#12 feature. So in terms of NET versions you need to be targeting Net8.0 or higher.
For reference: Whats-new-csharp-12
See also answer from @Sebastian Schumann about enabling language features for C#12 in a lower framework version. Take care with this approach - it is of course great to have the new language features but it is not without risks. From the MS docs: [The] default [language version choice] ensures you don't use a language that requires types or runtime behavior not available in your target framework. Choosing a language version newer than the default can cause hard to diagnose compile-time and runtime errors.

Introducing the latest language features is sufficient for collection initializers. There is no need to target net80.

I never encountered problems when using <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>. The compiler will prevent you from using features not supported by the target framework. A problem can arise in teams, where not everyone has the latest VS or CLR installed.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes me too

A higher framework version does not necessarily have to be specified. It is sufficient to activate the language features.
The following entry must be specified in the project file:
<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>

Put this to the topmost <PropertyGroup> and you should be able to use the latest language features. This does not mean that all Features are available due to restrictions of the used framework.
List initializers are available using this entry in net472 as we use this in our projects.
The compiler has to support this features. You need to use VS2022 (17.8+ might be sufficient).
